# What is the direction of rotation of the motor?

Tags: chevrolet, timing

On 2005 Chev Classic 2.2 Ecotec, what direction do I need to turn it after replacing timing chain? I want to know what direction the motor rotates clockwise or counter-clockwise (anti-clockwise) when looking at the motor?

Answer (score 2):

The motor should turn clockwise as you are looking at the snout of the crankshaft.